# KeyStroke action with F8 not working?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, hotkeys, key-bindings

I'm using the following code to create a hotkey, which works. I was a bit surprised though that all the function keys are working except when I use VK_F8.

```
String action = "ExecuteSQL";

mExecuteQueryBtn = new JButton("Execute query");
Action actionListener = new AbstractAction()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oEvent)
    {
        onExecuteQuery(oEvent);
    }

};

KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
InputMap imp = mExecuteQueryBtn.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
imp.put(ks, action);
ActionMap actionMap = mExecuteQueryBtn.getActionMap();
actionMap.put(action, actionListener);
```

So when I switch this to:

```
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F8, 0);
```

I receive no key event. Using any other key like F1, F2, etc. are all working though. My key definitely works, because I use it in some other application as well, so can anybody explain me why F8 would be special?

Comment: Check your platform's control panel for supervening, system-defined keystrokes.

Comment: Yeah, that was also my thought, but it works in other applications.

Comment: Other Swing components may be using that binding as well and may have priority. For example JTable handles F8. See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for the binding of each component.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the controls have their own bindings.

Comment: And, the bindings vary by L&F.

Comment: You can change the global key bindings, see http://xmedeko.blogspot.cz/2013/10/java-swing-change-global-action-key.html